# How to check if Stream has only elements from Seq

Tags: scala

I have:

```
val stream: Stream[String]
val list: Seq[String]
```

Now I have to determine if `stream` has **only** elements from `list`.

I think about something like this:

```
!stream.exists(element => !list.contains(element))
```

and it is working, but I'm not sure if it's correct?

Comment: What makes you think something is wrong with your approach?

Comment: That double negation, I think it works ok, but doesn't look good. Solution below is simpler :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid the negation by using `forall()`, the counterpart to `exists()`.

```
stream.forall(list.contains)
```